# innerHTML replace pattern not work

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I saw a lot of posts about this pattern, but still don't understand why it's not work in mine code. Using Chromium on Ubuntu 10.04.

```
function showDescription(){
    var description = document.createElement('div'),
    eventTarget = window.event.target,
    newHTML = description.innerHTML;

    description.id = 'description';

    switch(eventTarget.getAttribute('data-par')){
        case 'links': newHTML = newHTML.replace(newHTML, 'links')
            break;
        case 'images': newHTML = newHTML.replace(newHTML, 'images')
            break;
    };
    console.log(newHTML);
    parentElement.insertBefore(description, parentElement.firstChild.nextSibling);
};

    var descParLi = descPars.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < descParLi.length; i++){
    descParLi[i].addEventListener("click", showDescription);
};
```

This code contained in other function. Strangely, in console I see value of newHTML, but in html have no changes, that's a problem. What is wrong? How to fix?

Comment: Well for one thing, `window.event` is only correct for Internet Explorer. The event object will be passed as the first parameter to your function if you add it with "addEventListener()" (which, interestingly enough, will **not** work in Internet Explorer).

Comment: Can you create a little fiddle for it ?

Comment: @Pointy: Oddly (I just learned this the other day) Chrome mimics IE in this regard by making `event` a property of `window` in addition to an argument to the handler. http://jsfiddle.net/SdMX9/

Comment: Oh that's right; I remember learning that recently. It still makes me a little sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't adding the content to the actual `div` you created.

```
switch(eventTarget.getAttribute('data-par')){
    case 'links': description.innerHTML = 'links'
        break;
    case 'images': description.innerHTML = 'images'
        break;
};

console.log( description.innerHTML );
```

There's no point in doing:

```
newHTML = description.innerHTML
```

...or:

```
newHTML.replace(newHTML, 'images')
```

...because `description` is a brand new element, so there isn't any innerHTML content yet.

---

**EDIT:** *I used `div` instead of `description` for the variable name above. It should use `description` instead:*

```
description.innerHTML = 'xxxxx'
```

Fixed.

Here's the entire function:

```
var i = 0;

function showDescription(){
    var description = document.createElement('div'),
    eventTarget = window.event.target;

    description.id = 'description' + i;  // <-- make the ID unique

    i++;  // <-- increment "i" so that it's different on the next run

    switch(eventTarget.getAttribute('data-par')){
        case 'links': description.innerHTML = 'links'
            break;
        case 'images': description.innerHTML = 'images'
            break;
    };
    console.log( description.innerHTML );

      // v----What is parentElement supposed to reference?
    parentElement.insertBefore(description, parentElement.firstChild.nextSibling);
}
```

Notice I added an incrementing `i` so that your ID will be unique each time.

This won't be necessary if you're removing the element before another one is shown.

Also, you have a `parentElement`. I don't know what that's supposed to reference.

If it is some appropriate variable not shown, then you're fine, but if it should be a reference to the parent of the `target`, then you should do this instead:

```
target.parentNode.insertBefore(description, target.parentNode.firstChild.nextSibling);
```

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't actually made newHTML the value of innerHTML, like so:

```
description.innerHTML = newHTML;
```